How to optimize the number of data points used to interpolate a fit over an unknown polynomial (with noisy data)?
I'm trying to find the coefficients of an unknown polynomial given that I can choose to extract a coordinate at any point but at a cost. The cost goes up as more points are chosen. When a coordinate point is extracted there is some error in the returned coordinate point. So I can choose to take a point at a given x value, and the returned y value will not necessarily lie exactly on the actual underlying polynomial.
It is known that the underlying curve is polynomial, but the order is not known. I'd like to know how to optimize the number of points chosen, given that there is a cost associated with acquiring new coordinate points.
I'm working at a high school level by the way.
Solution so far:
A potential starting point could be to take multiple (maybe 5 or so) points at the same location and get an average for the error. This could then be used somehow add an error to the polynomial that is fit over the data points.
I have come across Runge's phenomenon which can be overcome by selecting points according to Chebyshev's method.
